# session id in time stamp after http post request in php

Tags: php

I am struggling to get a session id for very file saved in htdocs(file is saved with time stamp) in xampp using http post request.The file is saved in this format 2015-08-13_11h30m05s0805ms_sid=_123.txt, but I am trying to get a unique session id at "_sid" for every file that saves in htdocs, like url session id

Php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) == true){
        $errors = array();

        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];//file     
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];//temporary file name
        $t = time();
        $date = date("Y-m-d",$t);
        $b = time ();  
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
        $ts = explode(":", date("G:i:s:ms",$b));
        $times = $ts[0]."h".$ts[1]."m".$ts[2]."s".$ts[3]."ms";

        $data=$date."_".$times."_sid=_";


       if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"D:/server/htdocs/server_files/".$data.$file_name);//file to upload to server
        }
    }
?>
```

It will be great to embed a session like url in time stamp(2015-08-13_11h30m05s0805ms_sid=_123.txt) at _sid for every file that saves in htdocs

Comment: so, what's the problem? Is there a question we should think about?

Comment: BTW **empty($errors)==true** is pointless.

Comment: I need to get a unique id(may be a number) at _sid in timestamp for instance, let me take a example "2015-08-13_11h30m05s0805ms_sid=_123.txt".So every file will have timestamp when it is saved in htdocs, but now i need 2015-08-13_11h30m05s0805ms_sid=12345_123.txt"(you can see the change at _sid=) like session id for url.                                   ´                                                                     Thank you for assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure start the session at the beginning of the code by the following php function

```
session_start();
```

then you can get the session id by the php function on your variable $data

```
$session_id = session_id();
$data=$date."_".$times."_sid=_".$session_id;
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: is that what you was looking for?

Comment: Yes,but I was working this way
session_start();
$session_id=_sid;
$data=$date."_".$times."_sid=_".$session_id;
Thank once again

Comment: without session_start() you can't get the session id mate.